# Python Tkinter Do Something when All Entries are Full

Tags: python, graphics, tkinter

I want to run a command when every entry box is full in a `tk.Toplevel` instance.

Currently, I have it so that every time new input is entered, it will check if all of them are full. However, this becomes inefficient because if a long string is entered, it will check every letter (because an Entry's `command` is executed every time the Entry is changed). Also, I have numerous Entry boxes (about 30 in total) that will be used, so this will become horribly inefficient.

```
are_EntriesFull = lambda master: all(bool(widget.get()) for widget in filter(lambda s: isinstance(s, tk.Entry), findAllWidgets(master)))

_packingWidgets = (tk.Tk, tk.Toplevel, tk.Frame)

def findAllWidgets(master, widgetsFound = None):
    '''Returns all of the widgets in a packing instance'''
    if widgetsFound is None:
        widgetsFound = []
    subWidgets = master.grid_slaves()
    for widget in subWidgets:
        widgetsFound.append(widget)
        if isinstance(widget, _packingWidgets):
            widgetsFound.extend(findAllWidgets(widget, widgetsFound))
    return widgetsFound

class GetWord:

    '''Window to get input from the user and create an entry for the word'''
        def __init__(self, master, current, total):
            self.master, self.current, self.total, self.mainFrame = master, current, total, tk.Frame(master)
            self.master.title(STANDARD_TITLE)
            self.wordFrame, self.typeFrame, self.infoFrame, self.buttonFrame = tk.Frame(self.mainFrame), tk.Frame(self.mainFrame), tk.Frame(self.mainFrame), tk.Frame(self.mainFrame)
            self.word = tk.StringVar(self.wordFrame)
            self.wordLabel = tk.Label(self.wordFrame, text = "{}/{}) Word:".format(self.current, self.total), justify = tk.CENTER)
            self.activateButton = lambda: self.okButton.configure(state = tk.ACTIVE) if are_EntriesFull(self.master) else None
            self.wordEntry = tk.Entry(self.wordFrame, width = 50, justify = tk.CENTER, textvariable = self.word, command = self.activateButton)
                    # bunch of other code
```

Basically what the command should do is activate a button (I want it only to be used if every Entry is filled). Alternatively, I could just check if the Entry boxes when the Button is pressed (and thus keep it activated all the time), and only if they are full, execute the button's command, but I'd rather only activate it when they are full.
Is there any better way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not nearly as inefficient as you think it is. Try measuring how long it takes you to check the contents of 30 (or even 300, or 3000) entry widgets. You might be surprised. You would likely have to type several hundred words per minute before you noticed a delay.

For 3000 entry widgets, on my Mac I can check the length of all of them in about 3ms on each keystroke. This, assuming I have a list of widgets to check. It will take longer if you iterate over all widgets and their children which is a) pointless, and b) probably still really fast.

Comment: It turns out I wasn't looking at the correct information... Instead of `tk.Entry(..., command = self.activateButton)`, I had to use `self.master.bind("<Key>", lambda event: self.activateButton())`, but still the same idea. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 1):

Save the result of `findAllWidgets` and reuse that result instead of call `findAllWidgets` everytime.

```
#are_EntriesFull = lambda master: all(bool(widget.get()) for widget in filter(lambda s: isinstance(s, tk.Entry), findAllWidgets(master)))
are_EntriesFull = lambda entries: all(bool(widget.get()) for widget in entries) # <---

_packingWidgets = (tk.Tk, tk.Toplevel, tk.Frame)

def findAllWidgets(master, widgetsFound = None):
    '''Returns all of the widgets in a packing instance'''
    if widgetsFound is None:
        widgetsFound = []
    subWidgets = master.grid_slaves()
    for widget in subWidgets:
        widgetsFound.append(widget)
        if isinstance(widget, _packingWidgets):
            widgetsFound.extend(findAllWidgets(widget, widgetsFound))
    return widgetsFound

class GetWord:

    '''Window to get input from the user and create an entry for the word'''
        def __init__(self, master, current, total):
            self.master, self.current, self.total, self.mainFrame = master, current, total, tk.Frame(master)
            self.master.title(STANDARD_TITLE)
            self.wordFrame, self.typeFrame, self.infoFrame, self.buttonFrame = tk.Frame(self.mainFrame), tk.Frame(self.mainFrame), tk.Frame(self.mainFrame), tk.Frame(self.mainFrame)
            self.word = tk.StringVar(self.wordFrame)
            self.wordLabel = tk.Label(self.wordFrame, text = "{}/{}) Word:".format(self.current, self.total), justify = tk.CENTER)
            self.activateButton = lambda: self.okButton.configure(state = tk.ACTIVE if are_EntriesFull(all_entries) else tk.DISABLED) # <---
            self.wordEntry = tk.Entry(self.wordFrame, width = 50, justify = tk.CENTER, textvariable = self.word, command = self.activateButton)
                    # bunch of other code

            ...

            all_entries = findAllWidgets(self.master) # <---
```